# Received value must be a mock or spy function when mocking a class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am writing a test to check that one method is called when the callback is executed. However, it is getting me this error.

```
expect(received).toHaveBeenCalled()

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has value: undefined
```

According to [Jest automatic class mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock) adding the line `jest.mock(...)` should be enough to get a mocked class, but it seems that I am missing something here.

This is my test file:

```
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import Grid from "../../components/Grid";
import DetectFibonacciUseCase from "../../useCases/DetectFibonacciUseCase";

jest.mock("../../useCases/DetectFibonacciUseCase");

describe("GridComponent", () => {
    test("Should've called the run method when the callback is executed", () => {
       const { getByTestId } = render(<Grid />);
       const firstCellButton = getByTestId("cell-testid-0-0");

       fireEvent.click(firstCellButton);

       expect(DetectFibonacciUseCase.run).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

The callback function looks like this, and **it is actually being executed**:

```
const calculateNewValues = (row, column) => {
    const updatedCells = cells.map((cell) => {
        cell.value = cell.row === row || cell.column === column
          ? cell.value + 1
          : cell.value;
        cell.color = cell.row === row || cell.column === column ? ColorConstants.yellow : cell.color;
        return cell;
    });

    const detectFibonacciUseCase = new DetectFibonacciUseCase(
        MINIMUM_CONSECUTIVE_APPAREANCES
    );
    const cellsWithFibonacci = detectFibonacciUseCase.run(updatedCells);
    cellsWithFibonacci.forEach((cellWithFibonacci) => {
      const cellToUpdateIndex = updatedCells.findIndex(
        (cell) =>
          cell.row === cellWithFibonacci.row &&
          cell.column === cellWithFibonacci.column
      );
      updatedCells[cellToUpdateIndex].color = ColorConstants.green;
      updatedCells[cellToUpdateIndex].value = 1;
    });

    setCells(updatedCells);
    removeColorsAfterTimeout(updatedCells);
};
```

I've also tried to use the `mockImplementation` method, but with no luck at all.
Any suggestion is well-received.

Jest version: 26.6.0
React version: 17.0.2
React-testing-library version: ^12.1.2

Comment: Where fn received is used in your test?

Comment: It is being used in the expect clausule:
`expect(DetectFibonacciUseCase.run).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `run` method is called by an instance of the `DetectFibonacciUseCase` class, not by the class itself.

While the Jest automock will work as expected, you need to access the mock class instance to check if the `run` function has been called.

```js
const mockDetectFibonacciUseCaseInstance = DetectFibonacciUseCase.mock.instances[0];
expect(mockDetectFibonacciUseCaseInstance.run).toHaveBeenCalled();
```